# Faster than O(log N) int set implementation in Java?

Tags: java, time-complexity, avl-tree, fastutil

Fastutil has nice class IntAVLTreeSet which has [`#firstInt()`](http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/docs/it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/ints/IntAVLTreeSet.html#firstInt--) and `#lastInt()` method, that I require.

Unfortunately, AVL Tree is O(log N).

Are there O(1) implementations of this? Is it possible at all?

**UPDATE**

I want O(1) lookups. Finding margins may be slower.

Comment: Are you looking for better than O(logN) insert and O(1) firstInt() or constant time insert ?

Comment: Do you require an avl tree or will any kind of data structure do? You can get a constant time min lookup with a stack

Comment: Are you talking about `O(1)` for `lastInt()` or what? Saying "AVL Tree is O(log N)" is very unclear, since complexity is in operations and not the datastructures themselves.

Answer (score 0):

The class you mention: according to [its source code](https://github.com/tommyettinger/Krait/blob/master/src/main/java/it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/ints/IntAVLTreeSet.java), `firstInt()` and `lastInt()` are already `O(1)`. The class caches the first and last entries in the tree.

If you want a more general lookup of any key to be `O(1)`, you'll need a different data structure.